# How can I change my account details so it says "not currently looking for jobs"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I accidentally clicked "Open to jobs but not actively looking" but meant to click "not searching for jobs" How can I change this feature on my Stack Overflow account?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by editing job preferences on your profile.

Try this click on your **profile,**

[image]

Then click on **Edit profile and settings**. 
[image]

Then under **personal information**, you could choose **Job Preferences** ,

[image]

Then select: **Not interested in jobs**.

[image]